# discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: extension is a required argument that is missing. | Discord.py error

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, chatbot

I am new to Cogs and I was setting up an example cog and when I try to load
it shows ***MissingArguementError***

Bot.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='>')


@client.command()
async def load(ctx, extension):
    client.load_extension(f'cogs{extension}')


@client.command()
async def unload(ctx, extension):
    client.unload_extension(f'cogs{extension}')

for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
    if filename.endswith('.py'):
        client.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')
```

And this is the Cog file =>
example.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands


class Example(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Bot Is Active')

    @commands.command()
    async def ping(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send('Pong!')


def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Example(client))
```

And it shows this error when i try to load the cogs

```
Ignoring exception in command load:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 855, in invoke
    await self.prepare(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 789, in prepare
    await self._parse_arguments(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 697, in _parse_arguments
    transformed = await self.transform(ctx, param)
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 542, in transform
    raise MissingRequiredArgument(param)
discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: extension is a required argument that is missing.
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Please always provide the FULL traceback, not only a line.

Comment: i added it in the body

Comment: How are you calling the command? Seems like you just type in `>load` instead of `>load (extension name)`

Answer (score -1):

You missed a `.`

Here's the code:

```py
@client.command()
async def load(ctx, extension):
    client.load_extension(f'cogs.{extension}') # You missed a dot (cogs.{extension})


@client.command()
async def unload(ctx, extension):
    client.unload_extension(f'cogs.{extension}') # You missed a dot (cogs.{extension})
```

Comment: I appreciate the help but it is still showing the same error